# Use jQuery to toggle CSS rotation

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

I'm already using a plugin to handle the CSS3 attribute. It works when clicking it, and rotates 45 deg, but when it is clicked again to hide the content it isn't rotated back. ANy thoughts on how to get this working?

```
$("#faq dt").click(function() {
    $(this).next('dd').slideToggle('fast');
if ($(this).next('dd').is(':visible')) {
 $(this).children('span').transition({ rotate: '45deg' });
 }
else {
 $(this).children('span').transition({ rotate: '-45deg' });
 }
});
```

You can view the live site here: http://www.revival.tv/lastdays/

WORKING SNIPPET:

```
$("#faq dt").click(function() {
$(this).next('dd').slideToggle('fast', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
         $(this).prev('dt').children('span').transition({ rotate: '45deg' });
    } else {
         $(this).prev('dt').children('span').transition({ rotate: '0deg' });
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: I think you should use `is(':visible')` after the `toggle` animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is like this. What I know is that when you trigger `slideToggle` of `dd`, `dd` is still visible until the toggle animation ends. Therefore you should judge if `dd` is visible after the animation as a callback function.

Documentation is [here](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

```
$("#faq dt").click(function() {
    $(this).next('dd').slideToggle('fast', function() {
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
             alert('1');
        } else {
             alert('2');
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

Sometimes, element selection is a problem. I just replace them with `alert('1') and alert('2')`. I hope you catch the main point.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Changing the second statement to 0 brings it back to where it started. I appreciate your help, and explanation. Made me think of it in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the rotation on a class, then use javascript to add and remove the class, so it flicks back and forth?

Comment: Thanks this works, but I am trying to find a better way of keeping my HTML clean.

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes a quick fix:

```
$("#faq dt").click(function() {
    $(this).next('dd').slideToggle('fast');


    if (!$(this).next('dd').hasClass('collapsed')) {
        $(this).children('span').transition({
            rotate: '45deg'
        });
        $(this).next('dd').addClass('collapsed');
    }
    else {
        $(this).children('span').transition({
            rotate: '0deg'
        });
        $(this).next('dd').removeClass('collapsed');
    }
});​
```

And you can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/crisboot/6Aj9e/

Answer (score -1):

Here's a [quick fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fAXn7/) with the basic rotation functionality. Implementation I leave to you :)

Comment: Thanks, I have that going for me right now, I am having an issue getting it to go back, pretty much toggle that animation.

Comment: Your fiddle has the same problem as the OP

Comment: What's demonstrated by the fiddle is how to do it manually (since you're having problems with your plugin). If you want it to go back, put in some toggle logic and put a negative sign in front of your degrees. I'm not here to do all the work for you, just help you.